# Contact Email field Update with Batch Apex class

Tags: apex

Can anyone please share me the code of how to update contact email field through apex batch class.

```
global class BatchUpdateContact implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    global string query;

    global database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){ 
       query = 'Select id,Email from Contact where Email != null';
       return Database.getQueryLocator(query); 
    } 

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> scope){
        List<Contact> cons = new List<Contact>(); 
        for (Contact s : scope){ 
            s.Email= s.Email +'.test';
            System.debug(s);  
            cons.add(s); 
        }
        update cons; 
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){ } 
}
```

This is my code.

> EXCEPTION_THROWN [16]|System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 16 with id 0030o00002bL0eSAAS; first error: INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, Email: invalid email address: b.levy@expressl&t.net.test: [Email]

Ans this is my error.

Comment: Hi Ansh, welcome to SFSE. This question is too broad and inspecific to have a single answer. Please take a moment to read [ask] and [edit] your question with more details of your use case and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This site isn't a free coding service, but rather one whose aim is to help you become a better programmer/admin by helping you overcome _specific_ issues. If you've tried to write some code, and are stuck, you should [edit] your question to include what you've tried so far. If you're new to Salesforce (or one of its features, like batch apex), https://trailhead.salesforce.com is going to be a better resource for you than this site (for learning the basics).

Comment: The text of the error seems pretty clear about what the problem is. There's bad data in your records. If you want to ignore them, you can use `allOrNone=false` via `Database.update()`.

Comment: As you can see, you have an incorrect email in your databse. Fix it and batch wil run seamlessly.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that some of the Salesforce sample Contacts that are auto-created for new developer orgs have Email addresses that are deemed invalid by Salesforce.  In this case, it's the sample Contact "Babara Levy" (presumably they mean Barbara).

If you delete this invalid dummy data, or exclude it from your batch query, your updates will work.